# TextField format number with wrong separator inside input

Tags: swift, swiftui, formatting

Hi I have some problem with format TextField input because I want to have same local formatting in each input and output. On image you can see that text inside TextField has different formatting. [image]

My simple code:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @State var value: Double?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(value ?? 0)")
                .font(.title)
            TextField("0.0",
                      value: $value,
                      format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
            .border(.red)
            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
        }
    }
}
```

Its possible to unify this behaviour?

Comment: You are only formatting the TextField so why not apply the same formatting to the Text? `Text(value.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)) ?? "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know how to supply a `format:` to the `TextField`. You can do the same to `Text`.

```
Text(value ?? 0, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
```

You can also do the same in a string interpolation:

```
Text("Some Text \(value ?? 0, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(2))) Some Text")
```

Comment: Hey, I realize I phrased the question a bit incorrectly. I'll make a new post, but I'll accept your answer as it correctly addresses the question